# How to filter xml nodes based on filter in xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb

I have a xml where I need to apply a filter to filter out some `nodes`. Actually the filter criteria is sent by client via request xml using `XPATH`notation 
 
ie. ObjectData[VData[@DestCode = BEANR0170100497]]

When I reply back to client I need to filter and send only above data. Can I do this with `Jaxb` or any other simple `parser`? Any sample would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is built into the default API, for example...

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(...);

XPathFactory xf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xf.newXPath();

String query = ...
XPathExpression xExp = xPath.compile(query);
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xExp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nl.item(index);
    System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: Ok, In this way I have to manually build the xml again right? say if my xml has head and body, I want to filter out some part of body. Still I need to manually plug the filtered node to body right? But I was thinking like automatically move the part I want and give me the completed xml. (with body and head, namespace etc.)

Comment: This example will only find the matching nodes.  Yes, you would have to create new Document based on the results